# Date Comparison not being accurate at present

Tags: php

I am trying to compare a datetime field to the current date for subscription check but the date fails the check

```
<?php if($membership['membership']=='Free'){?>
    <p style="color:red;">
<?php
    //if the date of the current subscriptions his hit expire it and show that account has expired.

    $expiredate=  $usbexpiredate ;
    $currentdate =  date('Y/m/d');

    echo "Date Now".$currentdate;           
    echo "Expire Date".$expiredate;
```

its still pritining out subscription expired message even though today is well before the expire date of 2018-02-28 12:41:57 Can I ask why date from the database is store as a datetime.

```
   if ($currentdate  > $expiredate)              
   {            
         //if it has expired we wish to downgrade the account automatically 
         // and set the isexpired flag to true

        $sql="UPDATE users SET memid='1' ,isexpierd='1' WHERE 
        useremail='$uemail'";
        mysql_query($sql);
       $message = "Subscription has expired. Please click below to renew subscription";         
  }else{
             $message =  "Subscription Expires: ".date('m/d/Y', strtotime($usbexpiredate));

  }

echo $message;

 ?>
```

But for some reason the check is failing even though the expire date is set to 2018-02-28 12:41:57 and I am comparing to todays date any idea as to why it is failing.

Comment: Compare dates using timestamp values or DateTime objects, not as formatted strings

Comment: @MarkBaker how would i convert the datetime field in database to a timestamp sorry just starting out in php

Comment: `$timeStamp = (new DateTime($valueFromDatabase))->getTimestamp();`

Comment: @MarkBaker thats great thanks what about getting the current date ie todays date in timestamp form

Comment: How do you get the current date.time as a timestamp? `$currentTimeStamp = (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();` or even simply `$currentTimeStamp = time();`